# Mongoskin connection to mongodb with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

Am trying to connect to mongodb throw my node js app using this line:

```js
const db = mongoskin.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/todo?auto_reconnect", {safe:true});
```

but it always gives me error:
[image]

And here screen shot from my code sample:
[image]

Comment: You should copy & paste the source code here directly - easier to test for others, easier to read, and the question stays valid after your uploaded image became invalid. Apart from that, did you try connecting with `auto_reconnect=true` instead? Are you sure that you need auto_reconnect and why you want to use it (because [others where not](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/issues/30) and I don't remember ever requiring that option myself)?

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options

> Connection options are pairs in the following form: name=value. The
>   value is always case sensitive.

What version of MongoDB? In latest documentation i cant find any option called `auto_reconnect` so It isnt required.